# How to Amending XElement using LINQ C#

Tags: c#-4.0

how do I amaned an existing xemement type object in memory ?

I have something like below XElement in my memory , I want to modify the same before proceeding to next iteration in loop. Want to add    to group all  nodes. Using xElement.Add didnt worked - so wondering whats the best possible approach?

`<Root>
    <deals>
        <deal>
            <dealid> D1 </dealid>
            <Trade> T1</Trade> 
            <Details> dt1 </Details>
            <Details> dt2 </Details>
            <Trade> T2</Trade> 
            <Details> dt1 </Details>
            <Details> dt2 </Details>
            <Group> g1 </Group>
            <Group> g2 </group>

        </deal>
     </deals>
<Root>`

Answer (score 0):

This has been done by using two different XElement objects and merging both just after each iteration - thanks for lookint into this.

Regards,